# Echarts - How to get image of the chart without creating an instance of it?

Tags: javascript, typescript, charts, echarts

I saw this method in the API documentation, `echartsInstance.getDataURL({})`.
But I need a way to do it without instance.

Comment: if the API requires an instance and you don't have one: Of which instance would you want to get the Data URL?

Comment: Yeah, basically this is my question. Is any way to do it without instance